# Do dynamic logistic models require data points to be temporally independent?

Tags: logistic, time-varying-covariate

despite my searching, I cannot find a clear answer to the question:

Do *dynamic* logistic regression models require data points to be temporally independent?

An answer, an hint and/or a reference would be appreciated, if anyone knows. Thank you.

Comment: What is a "dynamic logistic model"?

Comment: Sorry, here I am talking about dynamic logistic regression model (edited the question for clarity), i.e. one in which coefficients are time-varying.